# Why wordpress dymanic_sidebar shows category description in the title attribute of the anchor text?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am refactoring a wordpress website and I have a big problem with some widget registered as sidebar in the function.php

The registered sidebar:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => 'sidebar 1',
    'id'            => 'sidebar_1',
    'before_title'  => '<div class="box_sidebar_heading"><h4>'.WPEX_Theme_Options::get_theme_option( 'titolo_sidebar_1' ).'<span style="display: none;">',
    'after_title'  => '</span></h4></div>',
    'before_widget'  => '',
    'after_widget'   => '',
) );
```

This sidebar must show a category list and is called by the simple function

```
<?php
if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar_1' ) ) : ?>
        <div class="box_sidebar col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar_1' ); ?>
        </div><!-- #primary-sidebar -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Every category in the back office has a complex description in the wysiwyg  composed by text and images.

The problem is that the system function that generates the html list of categories put inside the title="" attribute of the anchors the category description, the one that is in the wysiwyg.

The result is something like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-list nav-stacked box_sidebar_list">
    <li class="cat-item cat-item-6 current-cat"><a href="http://www.test-site.com/category/my-category/" title="


                                        Title of the image








                                        Title of the paragraph








                                        Title of the footer





                        ">My category</a>
        </li>
</ul>
```

I can't remove the category description because it is used acorss the website and i can't find documentation on how put another variabile in the title="" of the anchor.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that completely remove the title="" attribute, so is just half of the solution, is a flag use_desc_for_title

```
// prevent the category widget from using the category description as the list item title attribute
function sjc_disable_cat_desc_widget_list_titles ( $cat_args ) {
    $cat_args[ 'use_desc_for_title' ] = 0;
    return $cat_args;
}
add_filter( 'widget_categories_args', 'sjc_disable_cat_desc_widget_list_titles' );
```

This is the link to the page where i've found the solution [use_desc_for_title flag](http://scratch99.com/wordpress/development/category-widget-title-attribute/)